# Force caption to be below of table for one table only

Tags: tables, captions

I using `\usepackage{float}` and `\floatstyle{plaintop}` to show tables' captions on the top.

However, I have table that includes 4 images. For that table I want to show the caption below. Is there any way?

My current code is:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.3in}{-1.3in}% adjust the L and R margins by 1 inch
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}  

            \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{./images/paper_2012_pixel_based_segmentation_important_regions} & \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{./images/paper_2012_FMO_2_MB_allocation_map} & \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{./images/paper_2012_corresponding_quantization_QPA_map} & \parbox[b]{1.5in}{\includegraphics*[width=1.49in, height=0.55in, keepaspectratio=false, valign=t]{./images/paper_2012_plaque_ROI_4CIF} \par \centering (d) \par  \includegraphics*[width=1.49in, height=0.55in, keepaspectratio=false]{./images/paper_2012_plaque_ROI_4CIF_QP_28}}\\ 
            (a) & (b) & (c) & (e) \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \captionof{figure}{position=bottom}[Atherosclerotic plaque ultrasound variable quality slice encoding]{Atherosclerotic plaque ultrasound variable quality slice encoding.}
    \label{fig:Atherosclerotic_plaque_ultrasound_variable_quality_slice_encoding}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please provide small, but complete document which exhibit your problem. on general, you problem should be simply solved by use of package `caption`.

Comment: Isn't the caption always placed there where the code \caption{} is placed? Did you try to place the \caption{} above \begin{tabular} instead of using \usepackage{float} and \floatstyle{plaintop} ? And if you want the caption to be below your table you can place the \caption{} below \end{tabular}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `figure` instead of the `table` environment so you don't need `\captionof` but can use the regular caption command as shown in the following example. As already mentioned in the comments, the placement of the `caption` command usually affects the placement of the caption in the output. So there should be no need for `floatrow`'s `[position=bottom]` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.3in}{-1.3in}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}  
    \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{example-image} & 
    \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{example-image} & 
    \includegraphics*[width=1.50in, height=1.20in, keepaspectratio=false]{example-image} & 
    \parbox[b]{1.5in}{\includegraphics*[width=1.49in, height=0.55in, keepaspectratio=false]{example-image} \par \centering (d) \par  \includegraphics*[width=1.49in, height=0.55in, keepaspectratio=false]{example-image}}\\ 
     (a) & (b) & (c) & (e) \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \caption[Atherosclerotic plaque ultrasound variable quality slice encoding]{Atherosclerotic plaque ultrasound variable quality slice encoding.}
  \label{fig:Atherosclerotic_plaque_ultrasound_variable_quality_slice_encoding}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend a different approach to position the images. In the following example, I have used the package `subcaption` so allow for subfigures with captions that can be referenced with the usual `label` `ref` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.3in}{-1.3in}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.50in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.50in]{example-image}
        \caption{}\label{first-subfig}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.50in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.50in]{example-image}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
        \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.50in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.50in]{example-image}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
        \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.50in}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.50in,height=0.55in]{example-image}
         \caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=1.50in,height=0.55in]{example-image}
         \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for all subfigures}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
\ref{first-subfig}
\end{document}
```